# Yet more Angular tag madness, this time about Angular Material

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I know many people may be getting tired of the Angular tag saga, but today I noticed the tag [angular4-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4-material) (!). Looking into this further, I discovered that the tag description for [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) actually described  what is now called [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/), the version designed for use with the older AngularJS framework, instead of correctly describing what is now called simply [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). Since [angular4-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4-material) had only four posts, I edited them to have the tag [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material), and also updated the description of that tag.

Poking around a bit more, I discovered more tags, such as [angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material) (156 posts) and [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) (490 posts; admittedly, this was the correct name until Google recently cleaned up its naming). Both of these should either be merged into [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) and deleted, or made synonyms of [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material). How does one go about requesting such things again?

Comment: Solution: any tag created that match `angular(js)?(2)?-?.*` requires moderator approval.

Comment: Also some folks use [tag:material-design] for their questions, which is often irrelevant